# springboot service json response with huge amounts of records

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have a spring java based service with pulls data from S3, processes data, mainly filters whats not needed maps to objects and sends it in a json response.

I have seen the data can exceed 10K records, although it works fine with increased memory, something doesnt quite feel right. Im sure there is another way i could do this which is much better.

Constants are S3, springboot, and java.

size of the response can range from 1MB to 25MB. Currently the 10000 records come back as 9MB

Streaming is one thing i looked at but im not sure how that would work when responding with json.

Comment: 10k records is not a relevant measurement of size. How large is one record? How large are all records combined? A few MB or few GB?

Comment: @luk2302 your looking at a response size ranging from 1MB to 25MB

Comment: Those are perfectly fine to just send to the client directly, not ideal but not really large.